# scss Mixins error

Tags: css, sass, mixins

The following scss mixin having compilation error
**Invalid CSS after "...  (base, $base)": expected ")", was ";"**
Unable to locate the error, please help

```
// Variables for Materiel colours
$primary         : #0293FF;
$primary-dark    : darken($primary,25%);
$primary-light   : lighten($primary,75%);
$accent          : #FF5252;

$text            : #ffffff;
$primary-text    : #333333;
$secondary-text  : #727272;
$divider         : #B6B6B6;
$base            : #FAFAFA;

$palette:    (primary, $primary),
            (primary-dark, $primary-dark),
            (primary-light, $primary-light),
            (text, $text),
            (primary-text, $primary-text,
            (secondary-text, $secondary-text),
            (accent, $accent),
            (divider, $divider),
            (base, $base);

@each $palette , $color in $palette  {
  .colour-#{$palette } {
    color: $color;
  }
   .bg-#{$palette } {
    background-color: $color;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing a closing bracket after $primary-text?

```
$palette:    (primary, $primary),
            (primary-dark, $primary-dark),
            (primary-light, $primary-light),
            (text, $text),
            (primary-text, $primary-text),
            (secondary-text, $secondary-text),
            (accent, $accent),
            (divider, $divider),
            (base, $base);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use vars map , You should  write like this "key_name" : $value

```
// Variables for Materiel colours
$primary         : #0293FF;
$primary-dark    : darken($primary,25%);
$primary-light   : lighten($primary,75%);
$accent          : #FF5252;

$text            : #ffffff;
$primary-text    : #333333;
$secondary-text  : #727272;
$divider         : #B6B6B6;
$base            : #FAFAFA;

$palette:(
       "primary": $primary,
       "primary-dark": $primary-dark,
       "primary-light": $primary-light,
       "text": $text,
       "primary-text": $primary-text,
       "secondary-text": $secondary-text,
       "accent": $accent,
       "divider": $divider,
       "base": $base
);


@each $palette , $color in $palette  {
  .colour-#{$palette} {
    color: $color;
  }
   .bg-#{$palette} {
    background-color: $color;
  }
}
```

Regards :)